# YII. Redirect from https to http

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to use one of API's, so they send the response like
https://domain.com/controller/action
But that page returns 500 error.

I've tried use this

```
class HttpFilter extends CFilter {
    protected function preFilter( $filterChain ) {
        if ( Yii::app()->getRequest()->isSecureConnection ) {
            # Redirect to the secure version of the page.
            $url = 'http://' .
                Yii::app()->getRequest()->serverName .
                Yii::app()->getRequest()->requestUri;
            Yii::app()->request->redirect($url);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/charge/chargePrivatResult$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it didn't help.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

check this out.. works great..

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/407/url-management-for-websites-with-secure-and-nonsecure-pages/

Comment: go ahead and put some code in this answer so that it can be accepted. Plus if the link ever dies, it's here for posterity.